# Best way to create a library project in Xcode for publishing on git or CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

I just want to know the best possible way to create a `library project`, which contain the resources that the library code uses—such as `image files` or `.xib` files. Also if any library needs other library (like-`AFNetworking`) then how to manage the dependency of other library.

In short, something like `Facebook sdk`.

Comment: So you want to know how to create a static framework and distribute it via cocoapods?  What searching have you done so far?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, i searched but not found any relevant solution about resources and dependency of other library. I found only this one helpful https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html

    But what about dependency??

Answer (score 0):

you can use cocoapods to create a static library ,which contain some resources ,librarys,dependencys. the https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html maybe help you.